# Given an array of ranges find the total distance covered?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Here is an interview question I heard about. You have a range of arrays where the elements are length two arrays with a starting point and end point on a number line. There can be overlaps. You need to return the total distance covered. How would you solve this?

Example: 
Input: `[[3,5], [1,3], [2,4]]`
Output: 4

My thoughts: You'd need to keep track of what ranges were covered and if a value was in a particular range. Not really sure how to do that though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my implementation.
Since every range has a min value and a max value (|min|------|max|)
If you have a **sorted list**, you can find the distance that wasn't covered by subtracting the current min from the last max.  If that value is negative, you know that no difference was found between the two ranges.  So you don't have to include that range, just store the new maximum.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //GIVEN A SORTED ARRAY BY THE INDEX AT 0 
        // (equal array[0] is then sorted by array[1].
        //If array isn't sorted you sort it here

        ArrayList<int[]> ranges = new ArrayList<>();
        ranges.add(new int[]{1,3});
        ranges.add(new int[]{2,4});
        ranges.add(new int[]{3,5});

        //getSortedArray(ranges);  //not implemented here

        int min = ranges.get(0)[0];
        int totalDifference = 0;
        int lastMax = 0;

        int MAX = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ranges.size(); i++){
            if(i == 0){
                //the highest max is the current index at 1
                lastMax = ranges.get(i)[1]; 
            }else{
                int tempMin = ranges.get(i)[0];
                int diff = (tempMin - lastMax);
                //Only if the range is above the last range.  
                // A negative means there is no difference.
                if(diff > 0) {
                    //Subtract the new min of the range from the last max
                    // This gives you the distance between ranges.
                    totalDifference += diff;
                }
                lastMax = ranges.get(i)[1];   // Set the new last max
            }
            MAX = ranges.get(i)[1];
        }
        System.out.println("Total Distance = " + (MAX - min - totalDifference));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to merge you starting intervals and once they are merged just calculate the total distance as sum of the distances covered in each interval.

You can merge intervals in `O(n * log n)` where n is the number of intervals. To do this, you sort them based on first point/second point. Now you iterate over the sorted intervals and to check which one should be merged. To understand why and how they can be merged, draw something like this:

```
a---------------------b
            c-------------------d
```

and notice the similarity of the merged intervals. Hint `max(a,c) > min(b,d)`.

**P.S.** if you want to pass an interview, it makes sense to think more about the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it (sorted)

```
def total_distance(intervals)
  distance = 0
  max_value = nil
  intervals.each do |array|
    if max_value.nil?
      distance += array[1] - array[0]
      max_value = array[1]
    elsif array[0] < max_value && array[1] < max_value
      next
    elsif array[0] < max_value && array[1] > max_value
      distance += array[1] - max_value
      max_value = array[1]
    elsif array[0] > max_value
      distance += array[1] - array[0]
      max_value = array[1]
    end
  end
  distance
end

p total_distance([[1,5], [2,3], [4,8]]) == 7
p total_distance([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]) == 3
```